# Windows8 Listbox Align Text Center

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

How do you center align the items of a Listbox using C# in Windows 8?

Here is my xaml:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="365" Margin="242,275,-1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

And in the code behind, I populate the listbox with the following code:

```
  listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = Global.availableDecks[0].ToString(), IsEnabled = true });
  listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = Global.availableDecks[1].ToString(), IsEnabled = true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a ItemTemplate to create visual representations of your object (list box items in this case). You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx)